# In python, can I write a function within one file that uses the filename of another file which imports it?

Tags: python

For example, say I have a large number of files that generate some data. One of those is called foo.py. I'd like each of those to save their output as e.g. foo_data.csv.
I'd like to define the function that maps a filename like foo.py to foo_data.csv in an external file, e.g. bar.py, so that within foo.py I can do something like bar.get_filename() to obtain 'foo_data.csv'. However, I can't seem to use **file** for this purpose, as that gives 'bar' even if called within foo.py.

Is there a way to write a function within bar.py that will use the filename of the script from which it's called e.g. 'foo.py'?

Comment: True, I hadn't spotted that. Should I delete my question as it is a duplicate, or leave it so other search terms will also discover the answer? @glibdud

Comment: I think there's a way you can agree to the duplicate, and it will close the question but leave it with a link to the other for future searchers.